# Make the submit button also send an extra value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a long form with a submit button that sends the values of all the fields into the address bar.

However, I want the submit button to ALSO add an extra value (&submitted=yes) when it is clicked.

How can I convert my button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="submit">
```

to do this?

The idea is that I could then use that value in javascript when the page loads along with the other fields:

```
<script language="javascript">  
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var LastName = urlParams.get('LastName');
var Submitted = urlParams.get('Submitted');
```

Comment: So your form is submitting via `GET`, with something like `<form action="/page" method="get">`? The fact that you're submitting a `LastName` makes me think this is a registration form of sorts, which would make `GET` completely inappropriate. You may be looking for a hidden parameter in the form itself (`<input type="hidden" />`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest solution: add a hidden input field to your form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="yes">
```

Answer (score 2):

well, you can use `button` tag instead, just like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="submitted" value="yes">submit</button>
```

Also i see that you use language attribute on script, you better use type attribute, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follows

```
<form action="/action_page" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="yes">
</form>
```